# Will Object.keys(myObject).forEach() execute synchronously?

Tags: javascript, object

Could not seem to find an answer to whether or not looping over an object like this is non blocking.

```
    let workComplete = false;

    let itemFound = false;

    Object.keys(myObject).forEach((key, index) => {
      // check thousands of keys for a match
      if(key === someOtherValue) {
        itemFound = true;
      }
      if(index === Object.keys(myObject).length - 1) {
        workComplete = true;
      }
    });

    // Is it true that subsequent work here
    // will not execute until the forEach completes?
    console.log(workComplete);
```

Does the code above **guarantee** that the call to `console.log()` will always print the value of `workComplete` as `true`?

Comment: will depend on what happens in `do some work` part

Comment: can you elaborate why it matters? Regardless, I will add `the work` to the question.

Comment: when you say 'it depends' i assume you mean it depends on whether or not a call to some other function is executed inside of the loop? In my case there will not be.

Comment: @DevMike they wanted to check if you were doing anything asynchronous. For example, doing a `setTimeout` or doing something that creates a promise. forEach itself is synchronous, but if you do async stuff in your custom code, that's on  you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided all executes synchronously. It will synchronously run through your function with the first key, then do the same for the second key, and so on until all keys are exhausted. Only then will it log out `workComplete`.

Comment: So in other words, checking the `index` against the length of the object to determine if the loop completed is redundant and not necessary?

Comment: Assuming you're not adding or removing things from myObject during the course of this loop (which would change the length of the keys), yes, it's redundant.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind elaborating further, what would happen if an element was added or removed to `myObject` during the execution of the forEach loop?

Comment: That's going to depend on what the code is. In the example you provided you'll end up setting workComplete to true early (if the number of keys decreased relative to the array you're looping over), or not at all (if the number of keys increased).

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will execute synchronously, partly because there's no async work.  If you were calling an async function in your `forEach()`, then it wouldn't be blocking:

```js
async function isThing(key) {
  return await checkIfThing(key);
} 

async function findThing() {

  // forEach will not await isThing, so
  // all calls will immediately after each other
  Object.keys(Things).forEach(isThing);

  // This syntax lets you do each await
  for (var key of Object.keys(things) {
    await isThing(key)
  }

}
```

You can use that Promise behavior to your advantage to do things like parallelizing a bunch of gets and resolving once they're all complete:

```js
async function getThing(name) {
  return await fetch(`${url}/${name}`)
}

async function getAllThings() {
  const thingPromises = Object.keys(Things).map(getThing);
  const things = await Promise.all(thingPromises);
  return things;
}
```